# "Сильнее чем меч"

Tags: пунктуация

Пожалуйста, подскажите, если использовать данное выражение как заголовок, нужна ли запятая перед "чем". Вероятно, все-таки это сравнительный оборот, и запятая нужна, но хотелось бы быть уверенной.

Answer (score 3):

Сравнительные обороты с союзом **чем**, входящие в состав сказуемого или тесно связанные с ним по смыслу, НЕ ВЫДЕЛЯЮТСЯ запятыми.

*Они для меня больше чем семья.*

Но это же совсем не Ваш случай. В Вашем коротком предложении-заголовке никакого намека на сказуемое, обычное сравнение.

Запятая нужна.

*Сильнее, чем меч.*

Розенталь, **[§115. Сравнительный оборот](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm)**;

Грамота.ру: **[(НЕ) БОЛЕЕ / БОЛЬШЕ, ЧЕМ, в составе сравнительного оборота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_68)**

Последнее не буквально по теме вопроса, но - хозяйке на заметку.

Comment: Согласна, что это явное сравнение (Например, "Слово ранит сильнее, чем меч" - сила слова сравнивается с силой меча)

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что **запятая в названиях, содержащих сравнительный оборот, выглядит не лучшим образом** (хотя бы потому, что объект сравнения не указывается). Возможно, что это не только мне так кажется, судя по названиям:

«**Больше чем жизнь**» (англ. Larger Than Life) — американская кинокомедия.

Из Википедии: «**Год как жизнь»** — широкоформатный художественный фильм. Повествует об одном годе жизни основоположников научного коммунизма Карла Маркса и Фридриха Энгельса.

**Но вот Розенталь против, он говорит: нужна запятая!**

1) Ср. также: **Год, как жизнь (название кинофильма)** — ‘год подобен жизни’, а не ‘год есть жизнь’. [§ 42. Сравнительный оборот](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147)

2) Запятая в заголовках **ставится на общих основаниях** (т. е. в случаях, предусмотренных правилами ее постановки):
Город, в котором мы живём; Подделка, которая не карается законом; Там, где создаётся настроение; Страна, идущая вперёд; Вот он какой, этот подводный мир. [Знаки препинания в конце предложения | orthographia.ru](http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg2.php)

Но это обычные примеры с запятой, не из нашей темы, а других нет. Поэтому запятая в названиях, содержащих сравнение, пока может не ставиться только вопреки правилам.